# Accessing Magento 2.3.6 REST APIs from localhost - Blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, magento, axios, cors, postman

### Accessing Magento REST APIs from localhost return error **Blocked by CORS policy**

i use the code generated by "postman generate code snippets"  on postman that works fine , but in axios and others types of ajax requests that wont work

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({


"customer": {
    "email": "adnanEmi@Shanal.tr",
    "firstname": "Adnan",
    "lastname": "Semi",
    "groupId":3,
    "addresses": [
      {
        "defaultShipping": true,
        "defaultBilling": true,
        "firstname": "Adnan",
        "lastname": "Semi",
        "region": {
          "regionCode": "NY",
          "region": "New York",
          "regionId": 43
        },
        "postcode": "10755",
        "street": [
          "Address Details"
        ],
        "city": "Istanbul",
        "telephone": "00000000",
        "countryId": "TR"
      }
    ]
  },
  "password": "#######"
});

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://blablabla.tr/rest/V1/customers',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=9e952ab096c07bf2851826b05454f8de'
    },
    data: data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

}

Answer (score -1):

## this is worked for me *magento 2.3.6 and 2.4.1 rest api*:

#### add below lines to <***IfModule mod_rewrite.c***> on **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "index.html" [R=200,E=API:1,PT]
```

#### and at *magento 2.4.1* must comment the   #RewriteBase on .htaccess

#### then add below lines to *<**IfModule mod_headers.c**>* on .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API<br/>
### ----- the below line is optional -----
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API
```